# "Unsupported Media Type" error in login API with cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with login in a API Software with PHP cURL.

```
//define variable
$utentesl = ...
$passwordsl = ...
$Appkey = ...

    header("CONTENT-TYPE: application/json;charset=utf-8");
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');
 
        define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookie.txt');
    

  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $paginalogin);
  
        $accesso="Username=".$utentesl."&Password=". $passwordsl."&Appkey=".$appkey;
       


      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        
    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        
        //login
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $accesso);
        //non funziona ma esiste: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $accesso);


        //eseguo Login.
        $login = curl_exec($ch);
        $loginid = json_decode($login);
        
        
        //stampo risultato se necessario
        var_dump($loginid);
```

This code return:

> object(stdClass)#2 (6) {
> ["StatusCode"]=>
> string(20) "UnsupportedMediaType"
> ["ResponseCode"]=>
> string(6) "02-001"
> ["ResponseId"]=>
> int(1)
> ["ResponseIdDescription"]=>
> string(21) "HttpResponseException"
> ["Message"]=>
> string(22) "Unsupported Media Type"
> ["Details"]=>
> NULL
> }

I need to get from app a tocken ID.

I tried to insert various cURL variables (allow - origin: * , ...) but still the same result.

If I add this code I get error:

> "HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed."

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Content-Type: application/json','charset: utf-8',  'Accept: application/json', 'Content-Length: 10000']);
```

Comment: Well...what headers does the API documentation expect you to set?

Comment: Hallo,
expect application/json or text/json.

Example:
    {
  "UserName": "MeinBenutzer",
  "Password": "12345",
  "AppKey": "DemoAppKey"
}

Example:
    {
  "UserName": "sample string 1",
  "Password": "sample string 2",
  "LoginKind": "MobileApi",
  "AppKey": "sample string 3"
}

Comment: Do you have a documentation link for it?

Comment: Thanks. So...you are telling the API that you are sending JSON (which is what it expects), but your data in `$accesso` is not formatted as JSON. That is the most obvious problem, and I think that is why you receive the "Unsupported Media Type" error. Instead you should make a PHP object with the right structure, and use `json_encode` to turn it into a valid JSON string.

Comment: Why are you calling `header` before sending the curl request? And why are you setting (or trying to set) the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Thank you
After `var_dump($loginid);`   I have also `hcurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header1);` to set header.
I added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to try not to have error.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you. I tried to add `$accesso = json_encode($accesso);` but not change error

Comment: Well that isn't what i told you to do, is it? Json_encode can't translate form-encoded data to json. It can turn an object or array into an equivalent JSON representation though - which is what my instructions were.

Comment: `I added Access-Control-Allow-Origin to try not to have error`...to try not to have what error, exactly? Unless you had a CORS error in your front-end mentioning the absence of this header, then there is no reason to add it. As a general tip: effective programming is not done by guesswork.

Comment: @ADyson
I added not only json_econde, but:
`$accesso = array('UserName' => $utentesl, 'Password' => $passwordsal , 'AppKey' => $AppKey);

$accesso = json_encode($accesso);`

Comment: For info, test with Swagger, return:
 `access-control-allow-origin: * 
 cache-control: no-cache 
 content-encoding: gzip 
 content-length: 197 
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Wed12 Jul 2023 09:45:12 GMT 
 expires: -1 
 pragma: no-cache 
 vary: Accept-Encoding`

Comment: OK. But that looks like the response from the API. It doesn't mean you need to send that header back to your browser!

Comment: You probably to also need to tell the server you're sending JSON by setting a content-type header in the curl request. So far you've only set one as an output back to the browser in response to requests to your php script. The answer below looks pretty comprehensive, please give it a try

Comment: I added this before curl_exec:
`$headers = [
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
 'Charset: utf-8',
 'ACCEPT: application/json',
 'content-encoding: gzip'
 ];
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); ` 

But I get different different (missing parameters)

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',  'Charset: utf-8',  'ACCEPT: application/json',  'content-encoding: gzip' `...these are all response headers. None of them belong in the request,  although "accept" can be used as a request header occasionally.

Comment: Simply compare the headers in the documented `curl` command with what's in your $headers. Do they match? No, they do not

Comment: But I don't see that example in the documentation anywhere?

Comment: Great! Write it as an Answer below

Comment: P.s. I had just looked more closely and found http://slmobile.ch/slmobileApi/Help/HowToUse  showing what headers to set, and even a ready made php example: https://github.com/selectline-software/selectline-api/blob/master/PHP-Demo/index.php . I don't know if you saw those?

Comment: Yes, I saw, but apparently I could not make it work

Answer (score 1):

With no means of testing this particular API and not knowing the URL for the login endpoint might mean that the following is invalid but I hope that it might be useful.

```
$utentesl = 'xxx';
$passwordsl = 'xxx';
$Appkey = 'xxx';

# This is useful to ensure valid SSL certificates in HTTP connections!
$cacert='/path/to/your/cacert.pem';
/*
    You can download a copy of cacert.pem from
    https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
*/

# Simple utility to print out supplied data in readable format
# will accept strings, arrays or objects as $data
function debugprint($data=false,$msg='Success'){
    printf(
        '<h1>%2$s</h1><pre>%1$s</pre>',
        print_r($data,true),
        $msg
    );
}   


# Parameters to send in the POST body. You want to send JSON payload?!
$args=array(
    'UserName'  =>  $utentesl,
    'Password'  =>  $passwordsl,
    'Appkey'    =>  $appkey
);

# Create the JSON payload using above array.
$body=json_encode( $args );

# Tell the server you are sending and expecting JSON
# "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" is a Response header!
$headers=array(
    'Content-Type'  =>  'application/json',
    'Accept'        =>  'application/json'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $paginalogin );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1)' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body );

# If the url is SSL enabled make sure you set appropriate options!
if( parse_url( $paginalogin, PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
}
# Add the headers
if( !empty( $headers ) && is_array( $headers ) ){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}
# Make the request and...
$result = curl_exec( $ch );

# Capture the HTTP response code & info
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);
$info = curl_getinfo( $ch );

# Process response or debug request
if( $result && $code==200 ){
    $json = json_decode( $result );
    debugprint( $json, 'Happy Happy! Joy Joy!' );
}else{
    debugprint( $info, 'Request failed - why?' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I Add this code to fix error:

variables:

```
$accesso = array('UserName' => $utentesl, 'Password' => $passwordsl , 'AppKey' => $appkey);
$accesso = json_encode($accesso);
```

And Headers before curl_exec :

```
$ Headers = [      'Content-Type: Application/Json',      'Access-Control-ALLOW-ORIGIN: *'];    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Then:

```
   $accesso = array('UserName' => $utentesl, 'Password' => $passwordsl , 'AppKey' => $appkey);
$accesso = json_encode($accesso);
       


      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        
    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        
        //login
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $accesso);
        //non funziona ma esiste: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $accesso);

$ Headers = [      'Content-Type: Application/Json',      'Access-Control-ALLOW-ORIGIN: *'];    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

        //eseguo Login.
        $login = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).